# How to reload a file with the same name using file_selector in Taipy?

Tags: taipy

How to reload a file with the same name using file_selector in Taipy?
The event comes only once. Reloading the same file is not possible. Is this a bug in Taipy?
I set the file path on exit of the event handler method to None. However, it doesn't work. Only refreshing the page helps. Maybe there's another way. If I rename the file and reload it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to replicate the issue that you are experiencing, so I am including here some code to show that file_selector are working as intended even for files of the same name:

```
import pandas as pd
from taipy.gui import Gui


file_selected = "NO_FILE_UPLOADED"
data = pd.read_csv("file_1.csv")

page = """
# Welcome to Taipy GUI

###File Selector:  
<|{file_selected}|file_selector|label=UPLOAD|on_action=update_uploaded_csv|extensions=.csv,.xlsx|>

###Path of the uploaded file:   
<|{file_selected}|>

###Dataframe:  
<|{data}|table|rebuild=True|width=50%|>
"""


def update_uploaded_csv(state):
    new_df = pd.read_csv(state.file_selected)
    state.data = new_df

Gui(page=page).run()
```

Here I am using two .csv files, both being file_1.csv and another file_1.csv in a subfolder; once you start the application and upload something (.csv, .xlsx) to the file_selector, the callback function will be executed, read the data, and replace it to the data table.

Comment: I ran your example code and it also doesn't work.... See, I recorded a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gPvM1QMZ_H6tUhe18xhYUJ6knuGPvntZ/view?usp=sharing) of the action. Uploading the file a second time does not trigger the event. The same happens outside of debug mode.